# Subclasses in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, subclass

I'm learning Clojure and I was wondering how to deal with OO-like subclasses in Clojure. For example: a master abstract class, two abstract subclasses (each one redefines some functions) and in the 3rd level, final subclasses that creates "objects" that will be used in the functions. No clue how to do this. However, I managed to do it with one abstract class to a child class, with defprotocol and defrecord. But I can't implement a protocol inside another. Thanks

Comment: Create a protocol to act as an abstract base class, then define protocols that represent each new "level". Records can implement more than one protocol, so this should work.

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://clojure.org/reference/multimethods (especially the part that Clojure eschews the traditional OO approach but you can achieve polymorphism in different ways).

Comment: @Carcigenicate the thing is, I need the records to just implement one protocol, which will bring the base protocol with it. For example: I have 7 classes in this order:
A->B
A->C
     B ->D
      B->E
      C->F
      C->G

And for B and C they need to redefine some methods from A

Comment: @JuanIgnacioM Then isolate the code that's common into a function, and define it in terms of the base protocol methods. Then any class that implements the base protocol can use that function.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need classes or subclasses. Represent your data as maps with attributes. The "subclasses" might have more attributes.

If you have a function that varies on attribute, then either use conditional logic based on attribute (if, cond, etc) or use polymorphism based on multimethods or protocols if you really need to.

In the words of the Matrix, there is no spoon.

Comment: I really need to look into multimethods one of these days. I've been writing Clojure for almost half a year now and have yet to touch them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do inheritance with protocols like this:

```
(extend <subtype>
  <protocol>
  (merge (get-in <protocol> [:impls <basetype>])
         <map-of-redefined-methods>))
```

Multimethods provide direct support for inheritance with `derive`.

Actual Java subclass relationships can be specified with the `:extends` keyword to `gen-class`. This is meant exclusively for Java interop, though.

Generally, it is worth checking whether you really need inheritance. It is usually not the preferred method of modeling in Clojure.